# Power BI Designer Preview - No Data Load Settings

Tags: powerbi

When i load the Excel sheet as data source in Power BI designer i do not see any Data Load Settings ("load to worksheet" & "Load to Datamodel") in the right hand side menu called "Query Settings".

Failing which I can not define any datamodel for my imported data from excel.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In Power BI Designer, unlike in Excel, all the data you load using the Query UI is automatically added to the data model. To create relationships in the data model you can find the Relationships button on the ribbon when you are in the Reports UI.

Appreciate your using Power BI,
-Lukasz

- http://dev.powerbi.com
- http://blogs.msdn.com/powerbidev
- Make a feature request: https://support.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi
- Sign up for Power BI: http://www.powerbi.com

Comment: You just can not compare the data model capablity of the BI Designer with the Power PIvot. The BI designer is very raw data model and not full blown capablity.

Comment: Now, lets talk about the solution or workaround -  Can i use MS VIsual Studio or SQL server and do the data modelling like we do in Power Pivot? Will BI Designer tool be able to read that data model? What i am trying to do is to find an alternate since the BI Designer tool does not read power Pivot Data model.

Comment: It's true that Power BI Designer does not yet have UI for all the data modeling features provided in Power Pivot. You'll see us add many of those in the coming weeks/months.  You could just pull the data into Power BI Designer instead of to Excel and continue from there.  If you're trying to connect to data directly within the Power Pivot Model, I think that's something to submit at support.powerbi.com as something we could add.